# Html 5 doctypes & quirksmode

Tags: html, doctype

My question is regarding HTML doctype. A doctype indicates a browser about what rules to follow while parsing an html document. What to expect when a html document has  ie html 5 rules but the browser is an old one ex ie 6,7?  Will old browsers misbehave in unpredictable ways? Will the document be rendered in quirksmode?

Comment: Take a look here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911235/html-5-doctype-and-ie-6

Comment: IE6 and IE7 have always misbehaved in unpredictable ways. They will continue to do so regardless of HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

> A doctype indicates a browser about what rules to follow while parsing an html document

No, it doesn't.  It indicates to a validator what rules should be used to validate the HTML document, and it has been co-opted by browser vendors as a useful indicator of the age of the page and competence of the author, allowing a browser to switch between [standards, almost standards and quirks modes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode) so that most pages, even old ones, render as the original author expected.  It doesn't generally have any impact on parsing, for example HTML5 parsing rules require the document to be parsed the same way whatever the DOCTYPE.

> What to expect when a html document has ie html 5 rules but the browser is an old one ex ie 6,7?

Expect the browser to render the page in standards mode but not support [any of the new elements or features](http://caniuse.com/).

> Will old browsers misbehave in unpredictable ways?

Mostly they'll misbehave in predictable ways, it's unlikely any single browser will ever do two different things given the exact same content.  The key thing to do, if users of old browser represent a significant portion of your audience, is test in those old browsers.

> Will the document be rendered in quirksmode?

No.  The HTML5 DOCTYPE is the shortest string that triggered all browsers to render in standards mode.  That's why it was chosen as the HTML5 DOCTYPE.

Comment: Thanks robert. I understood the need and effects of the doctype. It was enlightening :)

Comment: "HTML5 parsing rules require the document to be parsed the same way whatever the DOCTYPE.". Almost but not quite. The `<table>` tag does not close an open `<p>` element in quirks mode, but does otherwise.